# Use DELETE request for not purely deletion in REST

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have a dilemma regarding the design of my REST API in Spring.

**Situation**

There is DELETE request to delete users by calling `DELETE: /v1/api/users/{userId}`, but it is not purely user deletion, i have to re-assign user tickets to another active user before deletion.

User A has 5 tickets, when i delete User A, all of his/her tickets will be re-assigned to another selected user, then user A is being deleted from the system.

**My Initial Proposal**

I use the most simple solution

`DELETE: /v1/api/users/{userIds}`

And also with the following to accept id for re-assignment

`@RequestBody int assigneeId`

**My Dilemma**

My gut tells me that this is not a good way to design a DELETE request API, delete should just do what delete should do, i thought it for long time but can't figure out an elegant way to do so. Any ideas?

Comment: "[...] but it is not purely user deletion, i have to do something like [...]" Really, this is far too less information to give any reasonable advice.

Comment: IMHO the REST architecture is very limiting if you wanted to follow it thoroughly. Just design something that makes sense for your use case.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose i edited my question for clarification, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's imagine you have cases associated to a user.

I would build a rest API like that:

```
GET    /v1/api/user            : Return all users
GET    /v1/api/user/{id}       : Return a user
POST   /v1/api/user            : Add a user
PUT    /v1/api/user/{id}       : Update a user
DELETE /v1/api/user/{id}       : Delete a user
GET    /v1/api/user/{id}/case  : Get user's cases
PUT    /v1/api/user/{id}/case  : Reassign user's cases to another user [{id}]
```

If a client makes a call to ***DELETE /v1/api/user/{id}*** and this user has cases assign to him. You can return an [**HTTP code 409 CONFLICT**](https://httpstatuses.com/409) indicating you can't delete because of inherited objects.
The client will have to ***PUT /v1/api/user/{id}/case*** to associate these cases to somebody else.

Comment: well, actually there is a delete button to delete users, say user A, when delete button is triggered, it will re-assign user A's item (example, tickets that assigned to him previously) to another selected user, then user A is being deleted from the system.

Comment: The question here is to find out the right granularity in the API. Do you want to execute multiple actions (reassign + delete) in the same operation. In my opinion, it's better to keep it simple (one operation, one function). Then on the client side, when you trigger delete and the API return 409 CONFLICT, you must consider that you need an extra function to reassign to someone else (popup, select user, call reassign and then re-execute the delete).I would do it like that because I want to separate the logic between each operation.